# Automated Unit Test on Healthkit permission

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, travis-ci

I am writing a `react-native` bridge for healthkit that includes the initialization of Healthkit. I also need to write an unit test for the modules.

I would like to use Travis to auto test on the project. Therefore, I need a automatic way that can press on the `Allow` button. Otherwise, the permission UI will block the unit testing process.

So, I need to know how automatically press on the allow button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [this](https://github.com/PGSSoft/AutoMate) library in my XCTests, I didn't specifically test HealthKit alerts but it seems to be supported.

https://github.com/PGSSoft/AutoMate/blob/master/AutoMateExample/AutoMateExampleUITests/PermissionsTests.swift

https://github.com/PGSSoft/AutoMate/blob/master/AutoMate/Models/HealthAlerts.swift

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reach those buttons with:

```
lazy var turnOnAllCategories = app.tables.cells.firstMatch
lazy var allowCategoriesConnectionButton = app.navigationBars.buttons.element(boundBy: 1)
```

On my test I check if the popup form is displayed with:

```
if turnOnAllCategories.waitForExistence(timeout: waitForExistenceTimeFrame) {
    turnOnAllCategories.tap()
    allowCategoriesConnectionButton.tap()
 }
```

Keep in mind that base on your UI, maybe you will need to filter a bit more the results of **app.tables** and **app.navigationBars.buttons**